# How to configure list of Servers for Ribbon when Spring Boot Test WebEnvironment is set to RANDOM_PORT

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix

I have the following config for Ribbon in application.yml in order to Feign work correctly.

```
ribbon:
    listOfServers: http://localhost:8080
```

My IntegrationTest annotation configuration looks like this:

`@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = TestApplication.class)`

However when set to `RANDOM_PORT` Integration tests fail and I'm getting `feign.RetryableException: Connection refused`. Because Feign is looking for tests on port 8080 but they are on a random port.
When set to `DEFINED_PORT` all tests pass successfully.
How should I configure list of servers for Ribbon in order to Feign look for random ports produced by SpringBoot?

Comment: Remove ribbon.listOfServers. This is should be used when discovery is not enabled and you would like to specify the server instances.

Answer (score 1):

Use property

local.server.port

```
ribbon:
    listOfServers: localhost:${local.server.port}
```